# Password Input in django form hosted on google app engine not working

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am using django form for google app engine.
My Django form code :

```
class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
password = forms.PasswordInput()
confirmPassword = forms.PasswordInput()
test = forms.CharField()
```

Only "test" text field is shown up in the UI.

Am I missing something.

Using python 2.7 and gae 1.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PasswordInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput) is a *widget*, not a field:

```
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```